# Javascript not displaying popup

Tags: javascript

I want to make a pop up window appear on the center of the screen,however when i use marginTop property the window does not appear.If remove marginTop property it appears always on upper left side corner. I use php 5.4 . What am I doing wrong?

```
function show_popup(id) {
        if (document.getElementById){
            obj = document.getElementById(id);

            if (obj.style.display == "none") {
               obj.style.marginTop = 20%;  //if i remove this line it works 
               obj.style.display = "";

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `obj.style.marginTop = 20%;` is a syntax error. So, if you remove that line, there is no error and the script continues to execute. This has nothing to do with PHP btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to apply `"20%"` for that like as below

```
obj.style.marginTop = "20%";
```

Check Syntax over here [**Style marginTop Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_margintop.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set `obj.style.marginTop = "20%"` (with the `"`) ?

Answer (score 1):

trying wrapping your 20% in single quotes....

like this: '20%'